# How to transfer files from Remote Desktop connection?

Tags: batch-file, cross-domain, file-transfer, rdp

I have a few remote connections to manage at work and I'm trying to create a batch file to help me remotely transfer files from the remote connection without having to connect to the RDP and manually transfer the files.

All the connections are on different domains but they all have a common user.

I know I can use xcopy, but how can I authenticate the remote connection?

Comment: `cmdkey` may help to set credentials for another computer. `cmdkey /add:remote-pc /user:username /pass:p@ssword`
... do stuff  ...
`cmdkey /delete:remote-pc`

Comment: cmdkey did the job, thank you!